# Flask - Uploading some image files causes 500 Internal Server Error... but not others?

Tags: python, image, flask, cs50, http-status-code-500

I'm making a website using flask for a CS50x Final Project, and I wanted my users to be able to add images to their profiles. So I set up the following basic application to test out the functionality:

***application.py***

```
    import os
    from flask import *  
    app = Flask(__name__)  
    
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER     
     
    @app.route('/')  
    def upload():  
        return render_template("file_upload_form.html")  
     
    @app.route('/upload', methods = ['POST'])  
    def upload():  
        if request.method == 'POST':  
            file = request.files['file']  
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], "test.jpg"))
            return redirect("/")
```

***file_upload_form.html***

```
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Upload</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <form action = "/upload" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
        <input type="file" name="file" />  
        <input type = "submit" value="Upload">  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

After testing this out, I found that for the majority of files I uploaded, it threw a ***500 Internal Server Error*** with no traceback or anything. Two images worked though - both JPEGs and both small files (less than 100KB on disk). I can't work out why some images would work and not others. Ideally, I'd like my website to consistently handle images.

Any advice on where I'm going wrong?
Thanks

============== EDIT ==================

*redmicelles* kindly pointed out that I had two functions with the same name - sorry about that! The problem persists though.

```
import os
from flask import *  
app = Flask(__name__)  

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER     
 
@app.route('/')  
def myindex():
    return render_template("file_upload_form.html")  
 
@app.route('/upload', methods = ['POST'])  
def upload():  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        file = request.files['file']  
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], "test.jpg"))
        return redirect("/")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The terminal outputs the following:

- Serving Flask app "application.py" (lazy loading)
- Environment: development
- Debug mode: on
- Running on https://e08f1ea9-40e0-458c-8c38-6f7f5b5fb160-ide.cs50.xyz:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 113-512-723
  192.168.239.158 - - [06/Aug/2020 21:17:11] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -

So even with debug mode on, it doesn't give me any kind of traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Having two functions with same name(i.e. upload) will land you in an AssertionError. You are probably not using a production server (or do not have debug turned on) and that's why you only get to see Error 500 (Internal Server Error).
Kindly rename one of your upload functions. You could have it like this:

```
import os
from flask import *  
app = Flask(__name__)  

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER     
 
@app.route('/')  
def myindex(): #give this function a name other than 'upload' 
    return render_template("file_upload_form.html")  
 
@app.route('/upload', methods = ['POST'])  
def upload():  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        file = request.files['file']  
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], "test.jpg"))
        return redirect("/")"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've also turned on debug mode, so you could see Tracebacks

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate function! I turned debug mode on (I had to do it via the terminal) but it still didn't give me any traceback - only the GET request that loaded the page. Is there something I'm missing to access the traceback?